# Show different images in OpenCV imshow

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to show images to emulate some animation with OpenCV imshow. Currently, I have the below codes:

```
int display_avatar(int idx){  
    Mat image;
    char* imagepath = new char[128];
    switch (idx){
        case 0:
            strcpy(imagepath, "c:\\images\\a.png");
            break;
        case 1:
            strcpy(imagepath, "c:\\images\\b.png");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    image = imread(imagepath, IMREAD_COLOR);

    if (!image.data){
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    display_avatar(0);
    getchar();
    display_avatar(1);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I use `getchar()` to trigger the animation. But I find the program will popout two windows (a console window and a `namedWindow`). Only after I close the `namedWindow`, another window will appear. How can I do the image change within the same window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove waitKey(0) inside display_avatar(), and replace getchar() in your main function with waitKey(0).
Remove the namedWindow() call, it is redundant.

You can think of waitKey as the opencv version of getchar. In fact, c = waitKey(0) will also give you the character pressed.

Answer (score 0):

replace the

`getchar()`

fuction by the opecv-function `cvWaitKey(0)`.

The zero indicates that the function waits "forever" for your pressing a button. It returns an integer indication the character you pressed.

see also [Link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=cvwaitkey#int%20cvWaitKey(int%20delay))